# Problem storing data in S3 using @Lob annotation

Tags: amazon-s3, blob, amazon-simpledb, lob

For my app, i'm storing data in simpleDB, but since SimpleDB has a 1024 character per attribute maximum so larger values should be stored in S3.

I'm doing something like this ::

 
**@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

@Lob 

private byte[] multimedia; //to be stored in s3**

and @Lob on its getters and setters
The JPA query is giving no error....but NO multimedia field is being created either in s3  or simpleDB. Kindly guide where to look for solution to this problem

Also suggest how to  make the rows of simpledb refer to same multimedia object in s3(to reduce data redundancy) as when i did this by manually creating lobkey and tried to use that value in another object...it created a new copy in s3 with a new key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your multimedia files on Amazon s3 and store Public URL of that multimedia file on Amazon SimpleDB.

Let's suppose you have am image say.. **my_image.png**. Upload that image to Amazon s3 in your desire bucket.. say **my_bucket**. Generate public URL of that uploaded s3 object. It would be. **http://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my_image.png**. Upload that public URL to Amazon SimpleDB.

It will easy your task and you can sync your uploaded data over Amazon Simple-db and Amazon s3.

Comment: yeah, @Lob thing did proved to be a pain. I've used UUID class for syncing  uploaded data over simple-db and s3, guess that should not hurt. Thanks for the reply :)